# Simple way to convert datarow array to datatable

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, datarow

I want to convert a `DataRow` array into `DataTable` ... What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Why not iterate through your DataRow array and add (using DataRow.ImportRow, if necessary, to get a copy of the DataRow), something like:

```
foreach (DataRow row in rowArray) {
   dataTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Make sure your dataTable has the same schema as the DataRows in your DataRow array.

Comment: This technique is helpful if you get the error message "An invalid data source is being used for MyControl. A valid data source must implement either IListSource or IEnumerable" when trying to bind a DataRow directly to the DataSource property of a control.  Here's how to do it: `DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); dataTable.ImportRow(dataRow); MyControl.DataSource = dataTable;`

Comment: +1 I prefer this rather than `rowArray.CopyToDataTable();` because this keeps table schema and is not replacing it with new table object!

Comment: Very good ! But I would Suggest  to clone the DataTable before the foreach. It copies the format of the DataTable: newDataTable = oldDataTable.clone();

Comment: Hint: Your datatable must have columns created or it will not fill correctly.

Answer (score 215):

**For .Net Framework 3.5+**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("Your string");
DataTable dt1 = dr.CopyToDataTable();
```

But if there is no rows in the array, it can cause the errors such as *The source contains no DataRows*. Therefore, if you decide to use this method `CopyToDataTable()`, you should check the array to know it has datarows or not.

```
if (dr.Length > 0)
    DataTable dt1 = dr.CopyToDataTable();
```

Reference available at MSDN: 
[DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable Method (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx)

Comment: From where did you get `copyToDataTable()` ? I didn't find it in .net 2.0

Comment: This should be marked as a right answer since `copyToDataTable()` method creates a perfect copy of the columns of the selected rows, whilst `datatable.ImportRow(row)` method doesnt

Comment: this method isn't good if the table already has rows in it as this replace whatever already there. If table empty to start with it's fine.

Comment: I prefer this method as long as .Net functions are optimized. Don't forget to add the reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions in your project so you won't get frustated asking yourself why this method is missing (like me)

Comment: Remember to add System.Data.DataSetExtensions Assembly in the References

Answer (score 12):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

DataRow[] dr = (DataTable)dsData.Tables[0].Select("Some Criteria");

dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: I already tried like that.. Error occurs something like "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Comment: AS Jay pointed out, Make sure your dataTable has the same schema as the DataRows in your DataRow array

Comment: Yes.. I tried. I used Datatable1=datatable2.Clone(); Now it is working... Thank you :-)

Comment: I tried this with a row array and it didn't work.  For each row in the row array, I created a new row, copied the ItemArray property from the original row and then the add worked.

Comment: This does not seem to work in .NET Framework 4.0 with the sample as posted, nor with "dt" being cloned from dstata.tables[0]. @joe's answer did end up working for my purposes. No-Clone Version error: "`Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.`". With-Clone Version Error: "`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRow> in StoreOrder Column. Expected type is Int64.`"  Note: `StoreOrder` is the first column in the table schema. Seems it's trying to jam entire datarow into that first column

Comment: It tries to make ONE datarow, using it's input as "The array of values that are used to create the new row". Not good by any measure.

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to use a DataView

```
// Create a DataTable
DataTable table = new DataTable()
...

// Filter and Sort expressions
string expression = "[Birth Year] >= 1983"; 
string sortOrder = "[Birth Year] ASC";

// Create a DataView using the table as its source and the filter and sort expressions
DataView dv = new DataView(table, expression, sortOrder, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

// Convert the DataView to a DataTable
DataTable new_table = dv.ToTable("NewTableName");
```

Answer (score 11):

**Simple way is:**

```
// dtData is DataTable that contain data
DataTable dt = dtData.Select("Condition=1").CopyToDataTable();

// or existing typed DataTable dt
dt.Merge(dtData.Select("Condition=1").CopyToDataTable());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
DataTable Assetdaterow =
    (
        from s in dtResourceTable.AsEnumerable()
        where s.Field<DateTime>("Date") == Convert.ToDateTime(AssetDate)
        select s
    ).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DataTable dt = myDataRowCollection.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataRow dr in drResults)
{ 
    dt.ImportRow(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

.Net 3.5+ added DataTableExtensions, use DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable Method

For datarow array just use .CopyToDataTable() and it will return datatable.

For single datarow use

```
new DataRow[] { myDataRow }.CopyToDataTable()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use System.Linq like this:

```
if (dataRows != null && dataRows.Length > 0)
{
   dataTable = dataRows.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution. It should work fine.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = dsData.Tables[0].Clone();
DataRows[] drResults = dsData.Tables[0].Select("ColName = 'criteria');

foreach(DataRow dr in drResults)
{
    object[] row = dr.ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone needs it in VB.NET:

```
Dim dataRow as DataRow
Dim yourNewDataTable as new datatable
For Each dataRow In yourArray
     yourNewDataTable.ImportRow(dataRow)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the structure of Data table first then import rows using for loop

```
DataTable dataTable =dtExisting.Clone();
foreach (DataRow row in rowArray) {
   dataTable.ImportRow(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable = OldDataTable.Tables[0].Clone();
foreach(DataRow dr in RowData.Tables[0].Rows)
{
 DataRow AddNewRow = dataTable.AddNewRow();
 AddNewRow.ItemArray = dr.ItemArray;
 dataTable.Rows.Add(AddNewRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void AddRange(this DataColumnCollection @this, params string[] columns)
        {
            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                @this.Add(column);
            }
        }
        public static DataTable ConvertEnumerableRowCollectionToDataTable(EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> drs, string[] columns)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(columns);
            foreach (DataRow dr in drs)
            {

                dt.ImportRow(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }
```