# Convert a DataRow[] to DataTable without losing its DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, datarow

I am working with DataSets and DataTables in C#.

My first problem was how to convert a DataRow[] object to DataTable, which I solved with this link:

[simple-way-to-convert-datarow-array-to-datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122511/simple-way-to-convert-datarow-array-to-datatable)

So, What I did was the following:

```
// Gets the rows according to the relation
DataRow[] rows = someDataRow.GetChildRows("the_table_relation");
DataTable newDataTable = rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

All the data that I am work with is in a single DataSet, so, my problem is that my object `newDataTable` does not contain the reference to my DataSet anymore (ie `newDataTable.DataSet` is equal to `null`).

**Is there a way to make the conversion without losing the reference to my DataSet??**

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tell us more about this DataSet you already have...

Comment: Nothing special, it's just a DataSet with some tables and relations between them

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presumably you already *have* a `DataTable`? If so, use an [overload of `CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx) which takes the *existing* table as an argument:

```
rows.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>(existingTable, LoadOption.Upsert);
```

Alternatively, could you just use [`DataTableCollection.Add(DataTable)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4zy2kc.aspx)?

```
dataSet.Tables.Add(table);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately for some reasons I need to convert the DataRow[] object to a new DataTable without losing its DataSet reference

Answer (score 4):

```
 DataView DV = MyDataTable.AsDataView();
 DV.RowFilter = "Id = '" + RecordId + "'";
 DataTable newDataTable = DV.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution may be contained in Jon Skeet's answer
`dataSet.Tables.Add(newDataTable)`

The thing is that the newDataTable doesn't have a DataSet child control but rather a DataSet parent control.  That is, a DataSet can contain Tables while the newDataTable's DataSet is the "DataSet that owns newDataTable" which in the case of the table you're creating above is null until added to a DataSet.