# How to bind data to a dropdownlist after applying filter on the table

Tags: c#, datatable, dropdown

I want to bind datatable to a dropdownlist. But before binding i am applying on the datatable so that i will get only the selected rows from the datatable.

I am using below code

```
DataTable table1 = (DataTable)Session["dtTable"];
       ddlSection.DataSource = table.Select("Section like 'Test'");
        ddlSection.DataTextField = "Quest";
        ddlSection.DataValueField = "ouestID";
        ddlSection.DataBind();
```

I get an error saying "System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'Quest'"
Actually after applying the filter to the table Column name gets removed.

How can I code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rubber423 mentioned the table1.Select will return datarow array it won't have datacolumn to be used. You can use dataview for filtering and binding to dropdownlist as,

```
DataTable table1 = (DataTable)Session["dtTable"];
DataView dataView = table1.DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = "Section like 'Test'";
ddlSection.DataSource = dataView;
ddlSection.DataTextField = "Quest";
ddlSection.DataValueField = "ouestID";
ddlSection.DataBind();
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that filtering method returns a DataRow array, so there is no DataColumn. The naive solution from me would be [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122511/simple-way-to-convert-datarow-array-to-datatable).

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Select("Section like 'Test'")) {
    dataTable.ImportRow(row); //then set dataTable as DataSource
}
```

Covert the DataRow array into a DataTable and DataBind. There is likely a better solution to this out there.