# DataTable Rows.Add() property only adding empty rows even when using a populated DataRow

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView that im trying to empty and then put data back into but no matter what method I try to fill the dgv I only get empty rows.

I have this code but no matter what I try, `dt.Rows.Add(sortestStus[row])` always results in an empty row being added.

```
sortedStus = Split_List(stuRows);

DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvClassStuInfo.DataSource;
dgvClassStuInfo.DataSource = dt;
dt.Clear();

for (int row = 0; row < sortedStus.Count; row++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(sortedStus[row]);
}
```

`sortedStus` is a `List<DataRow>` filled by a merge sort - this works as intended and `sortedStus` is filled with rows that have their intended data. `dt.Clear();` is working as intended and removing all rows but its the for loop that is causing issues.

I've tried `dt.NewRow();` and adding each item individually but it still didn't work and I've also tried refreshing both the dgv and the datatable and that also didn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

ETA: sorry if this is a duplicate question but I can't seem to find any with this problem, only trying to actually add the empty rows.

ETA2: trying `dt.Rows.Clear();` as Anonymous suggested has the same behaviour

Comment: Don't you want `dt.rows.Clear();` instead of `dt.Clear();` ? Because you are clearing the table structure in addition to the data.

Comment: Just tried that and it has the same behaviour but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I would suggest adding a BindingSource, so that changes to the datatable are reflected immediately in the DGV. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) is an example. You should add some prints in your loop to check the data you are trying to add.

Comment: You need to clarify “what” `sortedStus` IS… you state that _”sortedStus is a DataRow list”_ … and this is odd. Does this mean that `sortedStus` is a `List<DataRow>`? If this is the case, then can you show what `Split_List(stuRows);` is doing and what it is returning? I am just saying that it is odd to have a "List" of `DataRows` since the `DataRows` MUST have originated from some `DataTable`. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: ```sortedStus``` is a ```List<DataRow>``` yes. ```Split_List(stuRows)``` is there to recursively break the list down into ```List<DataRow>```s of length 1 and which will have a field in them compared and sorted by another method, ```Sort_Lists``` that returns a ```List<DataRow>```. This works as intended and correctly orders the ```DataRows```. The ```DataRows``` originate from a ```DataGridView``` and are added to another ```List<DataRow>```, ```stuRows```, via a foreach loop that converts a ```DataRowView``` to a ```DataRow``` and then adds that to ```stuRows``` - this also works as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FIGURED OUT A SOLUTION

my question was actually a duplicate of [Simple way to convert datarow array to datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122511)

I needed to initialise `dt` as a new instance of `DataTable` and fill it using `sortedStus.CopyToDataTable()` and then setting the datasource of my `DataGridView` to `dt`.

Closing question now.