Slowness when sending information from a DataGridView of a form to another DataGridView of another form
I have a form2 that opens from another form1, in form2 I have a DataGridView where I show the results of a search to the database. In this DataGridView of form2 I have a column with checkboxes to select which records I want to return to a Datagridview of form1.
The problem I have is that for a few records it is fast, but if I try to return 200 records, this process takes a long time and there are cases in which I will probably need to return 3000 records or more. How could I do this faster?
At the moment I am doing it through an interface in form 1, I go through all the results of the datagridview in form 2 and through the interface I am returning the results to the datagridview of form 1.
In form2, for each record I want to send I do this: I verify that the checkbox is checked, I verify that the phone complies with a format and if everything is correct I implement the interface
                    for (int i = 0; i < dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows[i].Cells["agregar"].Value))
                        {
                            
                            bool isMatach = Regex.IsMatch(dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows[i].Cells["Telefono"].Value.ToString(), "^(3)(\\d{9})$");
                            if (!isMatach)
                            {
                                codigosTelefonoError.Add(dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows[i].Cells["codigo"].Value.ToString());
                                TelefonoError.Add(dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows[i].Cells["Telefono"].Value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DataGridViewRow row1 = dgvResutadoBusquedaBA.Rows[i] as DataGridViewRow;
                                interfaz1.tableDatosEntrantes(row1);                               
                            }
                        }
                    }

and in form 1 I do this:
    internal interface interfazDatosEntrantes
    {
        void tableDatosEntrantes(DataGridViewRow row1);
    }

and now in the procedure "tablaDatosEntrantes" I receive the DataGridViewRow and insert it into the DataGridView of form1

this process takes a long time Hours? Minutes? Seconds? What would be an acceptable time? Please specify a wall-clock number that we can measure.

Are you sure it isn't the form update that causes the issue? How much time does it take if you don't call interfaz1.tableDatosEntrantes(row1);  (assuming codigosTelefonoError and TelefonoError aren't references to controls either)

A datagridview does have an interface ISupportInitialize. Before your loop starts, call BeginInit on each control that gets updated inside the loop, including on other open forms, and call EndInit on each control after the loop.

You may consider binding the DataGridView to a DataTable and then work with the data in the DataTable.
Below shows how to use a DataTable with a DataGridView. The columns for the DataGridView are created using the column names that exist in the DataTable. I also show how one can retrieve data from a database into a DataTable, then add a column (name: IsChecked) that can be used for a CheckBox in the DataGridView.
Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) (name: DataGridViewPassDesiredResultsToMainForm)
Open Solution Explorer:

In VS menu, click View
Select Solution Explorer

Open Properties Window:

In VS menu, click View
Select Properties Window

Open Toolbox:

In VS menu, click View
Select Toolbox


Rename Form1 to FrmMain

In Solution Explorer, right-click Form1.cs and select Rename (name: FrmMain.cs)
When prompted You are renaming a file. Would you also like to perform a rename in this project of all references to the code element 'Form1'? Click Yes.
In the Properties Window, select FrmMain. Change the Text property value to FrmMain.

Add a Button to FrmMain (name: buttonDisplayForm2; Text: 'Display Form2')

In Solution Explorer, right-click FrmMain.cs and select View Designer
From the Toolbox drag a Button onto FrmMain
Double-click the Button (name: buttonDisplayForm2) to add the Click event handler to the form.

FrmMain should look similar to the following:


Add a Form to the project (name: Form2.cs)

In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>.
Select Add
Select Form (Windows Forms)... (name: Form2.cs)
Click Add

Add Load Event Handler to Form2

In Solution Explorer, right-click Form2.cs and select View Designer
Double-click Form2 to add the Load event handler

Note For Form2, instead of adding the DataGridView and Buttons to the form using the Designer (as we did above for FrmMain), the DataGridView and Buttons are created using code at runtime. The code that adds the DataGridView and Buttons is in the constructor for Form2.cs.
Form2 should look similar to the following:

Add/replace the code in Form2.cs:
In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>. Select Form2.cs.
Form2.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPassDesiredResultsToMainForm
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        //create new instance
        private Button buttonCancel = new Button();
        private Button buttonSave = new Button();

        private DataGridView dataGridView1 = null;
        private DataTable dt = null; //holds data displayed on this form
        public DataTable dtDesired { get; private set; } = null; //holds data that will be returned to main form 

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Note: adding the DataGridview, 'Save' Button, and 'Cancel' Button can be done
            //      using the Form designer instead of in code here
           
            //DataGridView
            //create new instance and set properties
            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView()
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 30),
                Name = "dataGridView1",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(750, 345),
                TabIndex = 0
            };
            
            //add DataGridView to form
            Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

            //Button: Save
            //create new instance and set properties
            buttonSave = new Button()
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(325, 410),
                Name = "buttonSave",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25),
                TabIndex = 1,
                Text = "Save"
            };

            //subscribe to event(s)
            buttonSave.Click += buttonSave_Click;

            //add Button to form
            Controls.Add(buttonSave);

            //Button: Cancel
            //create new instance and set properties
            buttonCancel = new Button()
            {
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top,
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(420, 410),
                Name = "buttonCancel",
                Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 25),
                TabIndex = 2,
                Text = "Cancel"
            };

            //subscribe to event(s)
            buttonCancel.Click += buttonCancel_Click;

            //add Button to form
            Controls.Add(buttonCancel);
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get test data
            //ToDo: replace with your method to retrieve data
            dt = Helper.CreateTestData(3000);

            //initialize DataGridView
            InitializeDataGridView(dt);

            //bind to DataTable
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            //automatically check desired rows (all rows where telephone numbers start with '3')
            //ToDo: Remove this
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(dt.Rows[i]["TelephoneNumber"]?.ToString(), "^(3)(\\d{9})$");

                if (isMatch)
                {
                    //set value
                    dt.Rows[i]["IsChecked"] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void InitializeDataGridView(DataTable dt)
        {
            //clear existing columns
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            //set properties
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false; //hide *
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter }; //center column header text
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false; //hide arrow

            //add columns from DataTable to DataGridView
            foreach (DataColumn dataColumn in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (dataColumn.DataType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn dgvCheckBoxCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
                    {
                        AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None,
                        DataPropertyName = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                        DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter },
                        HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell() { Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter } },
                        HeaderText = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataColumn.Caption) ? dataColumn.ColumnName : dataColumn.Caption,
                        MinimumWidth = 10,
                        Name = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                        ReadOnly = false,
                        Width = 100
                    };

                    //add
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvCheckBoxCol);
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvTextBoxCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                    {
                        AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                        DataPropertyName = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                        DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter },
                        FillWeight = 100,
                        HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell() { Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter } },
                        HeaderText = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataColumn.Caption) ? dataColumn.ColumnName : dataColumn.Caption,
                        MinimumWidth = 10,
                        Name = dataColumn.ColumnName,
                        ReadOnly = true,
                        Width = 100
                    };

                    //add
                    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvTextBoxCol);
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

            //create new instance
            dtDesired = new DataTable();

            //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122511/simple-way-to-convert-datarow-array-to-datatable

            //get all rows where the CheckBox is checked
            DataRow[] dataRows = dt.Select($"IsChecked = true");

            //copy selected rows to DataTable
            if (dataRows.Length > 0)
                dtDesired = dataRows.CopyToDataTable();

            this.Close();
        }

        private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}


The following shows what Form2 looks like at runtime:


Now, add/replace the code in FrmMain.cs:
In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>. Select FrmMain.cs.
FrmMain.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridViewPassDesiredResultsToMainForm
{
    public partial class FrmMain : Form
    {
        private Form2 frm2 = null;
        private DataTable dtDesired = new DataTable(); //holds the data selected by the user

        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DisplayDataTable()
        {
            //for testing: displays the data in the DataTable
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (dtDesired != null && dtDesired.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dtDesired.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //create reference
                    DataRow dataRow = dtDesired.Rows[i];

                    sb.AppendFormat($"[{i.ToString("000000")}]: ");

                    foreach (DataColumn col in dtDesired.Columns)
                    {
                        if (dataRow[col.ColumnName] != DBNull.Value && dataRow[col.ColumnName] != null)
                            sb.AppendFormat($"{col.ColumnName}: '{dataRow[col.ColumnName].ToString()}' ");
                    }

                    sb.AppendFormat(Environment.NewLine);
                }

                //SaveResultsToTextFile(sb.ToString());
                LogMsg(sb.ToString());
            }
            
        }

        private void LogMsg(string msg)
        {
            Debug.Write(msg);
        }

        private void SaveResultsToTextFile(string msg)
        {
            //for testing: save the data in the DataTable to a text file
            using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                sfd.FileName = "Results.txt";
                sfd.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
                sfd.Title = "Save Results To Text File";

                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //save to file
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, msg);
                }
            }
        }

        private void buttonDisplayForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (frm2 == null || frm2.IsDisposed)
            {
                //create new instance
                frm2 = new Form2();

                //subscribe to event(s)
                frm2.FormClosed += Frm2_FormClosed;

                //show
                //frm2.Show();
                frm2.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("frm2 already exists. Activating...");
                frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                frm2.Activate();
            }
        }

        private void Frm2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Frm2_FormClosed");

            Form frm = (Form)sender;

            //set value
            dtDesired = frm2.dtDesired?.Copy();

            //unsubscribe from event(s)
            frm2.FormClosed -= Frm2_FormClosed;

            //dispose
            frm.Dispose();

            //display results
            DisplayDataTable();
        }
    }
}



Let's create a class that will hold the method that creates our test data.
Create a class (name: Helper.cs)

In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name>. Select Add. Select Class... (name: Helper.cs)

Note: The code below will create some test data.
Helper.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataGridViewPassDesiredResultsToMainForm
{
    public class Helper
    {
        public static DataTable CreateTestData(uint numberOfRows = 2000)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //add columns to DataTable
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "IsChecked", Caption = "IsChecked", DataType = typeof(bool) });
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "TelephoneNumber", Caption = "Telephone Number", DataType = typeof(uint) });
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "Code", Caption = "Code", DataType = typeof(int) });

            //add data

            Random randomNum = new Random();

            //phone numbers starting with '2'
            uint telephoneNumberStartingWithTwo = 2123400001;
            uint totalRowsStartingWithTwo = numberOfRows / 4;

            Debug.WriteLine($"totalRowsStartingWithTwo: {totalRowsStartingWithTwo}");

            for (uint i = 0; i < totalRowsStartingWithTwo; i++)
            {
                //increment telephone number; select random value for code
                dt.Rows.Add(false, telephoneNumberStartingWithTwo + i, randomNum.Next(1, 4));
            }


            //phone numbers starting with '3'
            uint telephoneNumberStartingWithThree = 3123400001;
            uint totalRowsStartingWithThree = numberOfRows - totalRowsStartingWithTwo;

            Debug.WriteLine($"totalRowsStartingWithThree: {totalRowsStartingWithThree}");

            for (uint i = 0; i < totalRowsStartingWithThree; i++)
            {
                //increment telephone number; select random value for code
                dt.Rows.Add(false, telephoneNumberStartingWithThree + i, randomNum.Next(1, 4));
            }

            return dt;
        }
    }
}


Note: If you are retrieving data from a database, you can use your method that returns data from your database instead of CreateTestData. However, ensure that your method returns the data as a DataTable so that it will work with the rest of the code in this post. Below shows how one can retrieve data from a database and then add the IsChecked column to the DataTable.
Add Reference (System.Configuration)

In VS menu, click Project
Select Add Reference...
Select Assemblies
Check System.Configuration
Click OK

Add connection string(s) to the App.Config file

In Solution Explorer, double-click App.Config to open it

App.config:
Note: The Server and Database need to be changed for your environment. For more information about connection strings, see here.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringWindowsAuthentication" connectionString="Server='.\SQLExpress'; Database='Testing'; Trusted_Connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionStringSqlServerAuthentication" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress; Database=Testing; User Id=testUser123; Password=mySecretPass123;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>

Helper.cs (used with a database)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DataGridViewPassDesiredResultsToMainForm
{
    public class Helper
    {
        private static DataTable GetDataFromDatabase(string connectionStr)
        {
            //this is a sample method that retrieves data from an SQL Server / SQL Server Express database

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                //ToDo: rewrite select statement to retrieve desired data
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Table1", con))
                {
                    //create new instance
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    //get data
                    int numRows = da.Fill(dt);

                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }

        public static DataTable GetData()
        {
            //this is the method that the user will call to retrieve the data from the database
            //it retrieves the data and then adds the 'IsChecked' column to the DataTable
            //before returning it

            DataTable dtModified = GetDataFromDatabase(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringWindowsAuthentication"].ConnectionString);

            //add 'IsChecked' column to DataTable
            //this is used to allow the user to select a row in the DataGridView
            dtModified.Columns.Add(new DataColumn() { ColumnName = "IsChecked", Caption = "IsChecked", DataType = typeof(bool), DefaultValue = false });

            return dtModified;
        }
    }
}


Resources:

Simple way to convert datarow array to datatable
?: operator - the ternary conditional operator
String interpolation using $

